# Проблема с выводом данных, задача, python 3

Tags: python, вывод

Дана задача, полное условие здесь -> http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1110

Сомнений насчет логики решения нет, все верно, однако, система выдает ошибку на первом же тесте.

Вероятно, проблема с выводом, можете подсказать что не так, и как исправить это?

Код:

```
n, m, y = input().split()
n = int(n)
m = int(m)
y = int(y)
tr = 0
for x in range(0, m):
    if((x ** n) % m == y):
        print(x, end = ' ')
        tr += 1
if(tr == 0):
    print(-1)
```

Comment: А что за ошибка-то ...

Comment: Для возведения в степень по модулю лучше воспользоваться функцией `pow(x, n, m)`. 999**999 можно и без этого посчитать за разумное время, но для больших показателей степени прирост производительности может быть огромным.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А так?

```
n, m, y = input().split()
n, m, y = int(n), int(m), int(y)
nums = [str(x) for x in range(0, m) if ((x ** n) % m) == y]
print(' '.join(nums) or '-1')
```